# Convert Cairo ImageSurface to PIL Image object

Tags: python, svg, ffmpeg, python-imaging-library, cairo

I'm trying to convert a Cairo ImageSurface to a PIL Image object so it can be passed to an ffmpeg pipe.

What I have so far is:

where svgstr holds the SVG data of the image as a string.

```
img = cairo.ImageSurface(cairo.FORMAT_ARGB32, 386,1080)
ctx = cairo.Context(img)

#render the svg as a png
handle= rsvg.Handle(None, svgstr)
handle.render_cairo(ctx)

imgPIL = Image.frombuffer("RGBA",( img.get_width(),img.get_height() ),img.get_data(),"raw","RGBA",0,1)

img44 = imgPIL.convert("RGBA")
img44.save(p.stdin,"PNG")
```

If I save the image to file rather than passing it to the pipe, I get some version of grayscale. When passed to the pipe it gives "IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe"

Ultimately I'm just trying to convert SVG data to some sort of object that I can pass to the ffmpeg pipe to concatenate images into a video without having to save the images to disk first.